# Ruby - Determining a return's execution trace / origin

Tags: ruby, methods, nested, return, trace

I'm hoping it's possible to determine the originating class / method / etc. of a given return within another method. E.g.:

```
# Ruby

class Stringify
  def fancy(words)
    return ">> #{words}"
  end

  def boring(words)
    return "- #{words}"
  end
end

class Yarnify
  def fancy(words)
    return ">> #{words}"
  end

  def boring(words)
    return "- #{words}"
  end
end

def printit(*args)
  puts args
end

printit(Yarnify.new.boring("Hello"))
printit(Stringify.new.fancy("Hey"))
printit(Stringify.new.boring("Hi"))
printit(Yarnify.new.fancy("Heyo"))

# Output:
"- Hello"
">> Hey"
"- Hi"
">> Heyo"
```

Such as:

```
## Desired trace
def printit(*args)
  puts args
  puts "Originated from #{args.what_called.method} within #{args.what_called.class}."
end

printit(Yarnify.new.fancy("This is a return!"))

## Output
">> This is a return!"
"Originated from fancy within Yarnify."
```

The content of the `args` seems to be executed before it's passed into the `printit` method. But I have a usecase where I dynamically mix multiple inputs that look identical, and thus need to log the source class/method of the `args`.  Scouring the rubydocs and playing with public / private methods on `args` hasn't been helpful thus far. Anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is `caller` what you might be looking for?  It contains a stack trace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'awesome_print'

def foo
  bar
end


def bar
  baz
end


def baz
  ap caller
end


foo

=begin
Outputs:

[
    [0] "./caller.rb:11:in `bar'",
    [1] "./caller.rb:6:in `foo'",
    [2] "./caller.rb:20:in `<main>'"
]
=end
```

Alternatively, there is a `caller_locations` method that returns an array of Thread::Backtrace::Location objects (see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html).  These would give you more control, since you could get components of the stack trace item, such as label.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. Using your advice on my above example:
    `pry(main)> args.send :caller
    => ["test.rb:23: in 'printit'",
          "test.rb:26: in '<main>'"]`

Comment: Identical printout using `caller_locations`. I don't see a way to get the class / method passed into `args` through this particular trace when outside classes and methods used.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now...you're right, `caller` will not help you because the argument is evaluated before its produced value is passed to the method.  You could pass a block or lambda instead so that evaluation would be deferred until inside the method, but that still wouldn't really help unless you inspected the Ruby byte code of that block or lambda.